# ASP.NET MVC Routing - Do you keep ID's exposed in URL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, url-routing

I have an ASP.NET MVC Application and the routing urls looks as follows:

```
foobar.com/users/8
foobar.com/users/90
foobar.com/exercise/details/5
foobar.com/exercise/details/400
```

So with this URL route, a user can manipulate the URL directly and change the ID's which are integers. What is the best practice of securing this so that users can't easily manipulate the URL ID's? How do enterprise applications handle this?

Comment: Typically, you want to allow easy access to friendly URLs.  it then becomes the developer's job to leverage the tools mvc gives us -  the [Authorize()] attribute which is applied to controller classes/methods as necessary. Further more, finite access would be granted based on business logic inside the controller methods.

Comment: so is coding the ID's as GUIDS overkill?

Comment: are you referring to encoding the uri? It really depends on the user experience you want to offer.  Will users of the site find utility in human readable URLs? Does the site allow anonymous users, do users gain utility to share links?

Comment: no value for the users for the URI to be readable. there will be no sharing of links, this exercise is purely to secure the URL without user modifcation

Comment: If access was properly gated, you would still have the same level of security. That being said, I don't see any reason why not to use GUIDs as as opposed to an Int.  I just wouldn't depend on it as my only means to avoid unauthorized access. case in-point is browser history.

Comment: What do you mean _"manipulate the URL directly"_? A user can type whatever they want in the the browsers address bar. You cant prevent that! You can however check if the user has access to the resource in the controller and prevent it being displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a well designed system, users manipulating URLs should not be an issue.  Even if you send the data in an HTTP Post body, users can still manipulate it using an intercepting proxy such as [Burp](http://portswigger.net/burp/proxy.html).

Relying on secrecy of IDs (for example, choosing IDs randomly) is also not a solution.  In pentester terminology, you will be vulnerable to [direct object reference](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A4-Insecure_Direct_Object_References).  The classical terminology for this flaw is violation of the [complete mediation principle](https://buildsecurityin.us-cert.gov/articles/knowledge/principles/complete-mediation).

Instead of worrying about what users may do with URLs and content sent to your server, you should be securing the server from malicious inputs.  The issue here is authorisation.  I recommend you have a good, thorough read of [Securing your ASP.NET MVC 4 App and the new AllowAnonymous Attribute](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/03/23/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-4-app-and-the-new-allowanonymous-attribute.aspx) and [NerdDinner Step 9: Authentication and Authorization](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part9.htm).

Answer (score 1):

A lot of applications are designed to be URL hackable in that the user can change values. A lot of users like to manipulate the url to change page number, record, etc.

There is nothing wrong with this As long as you make sure its all secure. For instance your Details action should check the user can access record 5 before showing it.